¿Cómo hago para hacer responsive los inputs group en Booststrap 5 para pantallas pequeñas con un max-width: 576px?

Este es el código, resulta que para pantallas medianas y grandes el queda con un formato responsivo adecuado; pero para pantalla con un max-with: 576px no queda bien. El input donde se coloca el texto, se corta como muestro en la imagen y donde vapara colocar las fechas de inicio y final, no se pueden escoger, porque también se cortan. Les agradecería mucho que pudieran ayudarme con esta situación, ya he intentado de todo y no me deja hacer nada.
<div class="container date-filter-container">
  <form class="filtrar-b d-flex gap-3 align-items-center" role="search">
    <div class="input-group date-filter">
      <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">Filtra tu búsqueda:</span>
      <input type="date" class="form-control" id="start-date" aria-label="Fecha de inicio" placeholder="Fecha de inicio">
      <input type="date" class="form-control" id="end-date" aria-label="Fecha de fin" placeholder="Fecha de fin">
    </div>
  </form>

  <div class="container d-flex gap-3 align-items-center mt-3 filter-options-container">
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Seleccionar ubicación">
        Ubicación
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Medellín</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Bello</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Itaguí</a></li>
      </ul>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Texto con botón de selección de ubicación" placeholder="Introduce ubicación">
    </div>


Usa una media query
/* movil */
@media (max-width: 500px) {
    .dash-content .title{
        justify-content: center;
    }
    .profile-content{
        position: relative !important;
        max-width: 100% !important;
    }
    .profile-content form{
        max-width: 100% !important;
    }
    .form .form-column{
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .form .button{
        width: 100% !important;
    }
}

Este es una que tengo yo en unos de mis sistemas y funciona perfectamente
